# Hangouts Chat API Card does not show Picture preview

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-hangouts

I developed an Hangouts chat bot showing a card reporting some data.

I would like to report on this card also a picture which is stored on my Google drive (.jpg, 1663x1225). The problem is that the hangouts chat does not show a preview of my picture, but shows the following:

[image]

I'm using the following code

```js
// Responds to a MESSAGE event in Hangouts Chat
function onMessage(event) {
  if (command == "test") {
      
      return  {
        "cards": [
          {
            "sections": [
              {
                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "image": {
                      "imageUrl": "..Picture URL..",
                      "onClick": {
                        "openLink": {
                          "url": "..Picture URL.."
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

I can access the picture by click on the image icon, but I would like to see the preview.
Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using the Google Drive URL(in format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/{FILE_ID}/view)? If yes, that's not a valid image url, you would need to download that image from Google Drive and provide a valid image url.

One possibility would be if you can get the thumbnail link from the Google Drive image using Google Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files). There you will have a valid image url and your bot should display it.

I hope it's clear!

Comment: Sorry for late feedback. I got the thumbnail link from the Google Drive image using Google Drive API as you suggested and it worked perfectly!! Thank you very much for your help